# How to install forever command without sudo

Tags: node.js, forever, dreamhost

I have a node server on a VPS through Dreamhost. I want to run my node process forever. Currently, I can run the process but when I close my terminal it ends the process and the website no longer works. What I have read online is that I need to do `forever node app.js` but I am not given sudo access and can not install the command `forever` globally. How can I either install `forever` without sudo access or keep my node process running even after I close my terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to activate Passenger on your VPS and have that manage your nodejs. Details on DreamHost KB https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215769578-Passenger-overview